# Is it appropriate that specific frameworks completely outsource their Q&A management to SO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, outsourcing

I am having a little discussion in comments regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56722711/tensorflow-2-x-c-api-are-any-changes-planned-from-tensorflow-1-x-c-api).

Here's the question as a screenshot (since it's likely to be deleted):

[image]

I don't think this question can be appropriately and concisely answered at Stack Overflow, because its main concern is about the development roadmap about the framework API for a specific programming language.

The OP insists that the only way to ask about it is using Stack Overflow, as seemingly it is used as advice from the framework community and documentation:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/community

Does this community abuse Stack Overflow to outsource any questions about their framework?

They say that *technical questions* should be asked at Stack Overflow, though I have serious doubts, this should apply for these kind of *development roadmap plannings* as asked with the question linked above.

I believe there's either a fallacy encountered with the OP's understanding, or abuse of Stack Overflow to outsource this frameworks complete aspects of questions to Stack Overflow.

What do you think? Is the OP's specific question *on-topic* or not?

Comment: There's already a help page for this https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: I feel there is some kind of business-model in *questions that can't be asked anywhere else* ... (patent pending)

Comment: @rene _"patent pending"_ He he, good guess ;)

Comment: Note, that OP is absolutely wrong. There are several channels that he could've tried to get its doubts solved. It just happened that SO was the first option, and it didn't consider any other.

Comment: Note, that the tensor flow community page states "For help with technical or algorithmic questions visit Stack Overflow". But there are also links to several other resources (GitHub Issue Tracker, Forums, ...). I don't think tensor flow completely outsourcing there support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(as this is tagged a [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question), so here's a specific answer):

Nope, I don't think anyone other than the administrators of TensorFlow can answer questions regarding upcoming features of their API, so I've voted to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

No, this question isn't on-topic. It's a [customer support question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions), so it should be directed to the company in question (not us).

With regards to your broader question, companies are perfectly free to direct their on-topic questions here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the policy is that companies are free to tell their customers to ask technical question about their products on Stack Overflow, but they should make clear that any questions that are asked must meet Stack Overflow's standards. It is certainly the case that some questions that might be appropriate on the company's own website are off-topic here.

If a customer of that company posts a question that doesn't meet our standards, then it should be closed. If several users post such bad questions and the company never advised them that they need to follow the standards, I think Stack Exchange employees will contact the company to explain.